# new input replace Instead of append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the html that I wrote for program

It's working but append is not working.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container m-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center">
                <span>Full Name :</span>
                <input id="name" type="name" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Email :</span>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <span>Comment :</span>
                <input id="comment" type="text" class="d-flex mb-3">
                <button id="btn" class="mt-3">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p id="demo"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

name and comment are inputs.

I type some text but append doesn't working and the new text that entered replace the first one.

```js
function SubmitComment(name, comment) {
            let newComment = censor(comment)
            for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                let demo = $("#demo");
                demo.html("")
                demo.append(`
                <h4>${name.val()} :</h4>
                <br>
                <p>${newComment}</p>
                `)
            }
        }
        function censor(comment) {
            var splitString = comment.val().split(" ")
            for (let b = 0; b < splitString.length; b++) {
                if (splitString[b] == "duck") {
                    splitString[b] = '****';
                }
                if (splitString[b] == "swan") {
                    splitString[b] = '****';
                }
            }
            var joinArray = splitString.join(" ");
            return joinArray;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: Why do you empty it with `demo.html("")` if you want to append to it?

Comment: Can you please add html and also `your code doesn't run` it give blank page. first of all please edit your question.

Comment: Swearing is **not okay** on SO. I've removed the swear words from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure why your looping the name property, but here is a working example!

```js
function Submit() {
  SubmitComment($('.name'), $('.comment'));
}

function SubmitComment(name, comment) {
  let newComment = censor(comment)
  let demo = $("#demo");
  demo.html("")
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    demo.append(`
                <h4>${name.val()} :</h4>
                <br>
                <p>${newComment}</p>
                `)
  }
}

function censor(comment) {
  var splitString = comment.val().split(" ")
  for (let b = 0; b < splitString.length; b++) {
    if (splitString[b] == "duck") {
      splitString[b] = '****';
    }
    if (splitString[b] == "kilt") {
      splitString[b] = '****';
    }
  }
  var joinArray = splitString.join(" ");
  return joinArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="name" />
<input class="comment" />
<button onClick="Submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```